# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpi4py'

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

When i try to execute:
mpiexec -n 2 python mpi_file.py, 
mpiexec shows error 
from mpi4py import MPI 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpi4py'. 
I am working on Win10, using Python3.9 and installed the lib with pip install mpi4py.
Why mpiexec cannot find the library, but when running it from pycharm it works fine?

Comment: Try running "pip3 install mpi4py" instead?

Comment: @ta4h1r i was installing it in anaconda env. When installed via command prompt everything's fine. Thanks anyways :)